# Find the factor level with the highest frequency in a column/variable

Tags: r

I've run this code

```
var <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C")
table(var)
> table(var)
var
A B C 
4 6 3
```

The maximum frequency is 6, for factor "B".
Is there a function that just returns the name of the factor which has the highest frequency, "B".
Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

var <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C")
table(var) %>% which.max %>% names

#> [1] "B"
```

---

In base R:

```
names(which.max(table(var)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using tidyverse:

```r
library(tidyverse)

var <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C")

df <- tibble(var = var)

df %>% 
  count(var,sort = TRUE) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  pull(var)
#> [1] "B"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>